# Get Column Name/Index on KeyPress/KeyDown in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

How can I get the column name/index on keypress/keydown event.
Suppose :
`$("#myGrid").keydown(keydownEvent);`

`keydownEvent(e)` is a function. Now how can I get from which column it has been pressed in the `keydownEvent(e)` function?

**EDIT:**

As @Rohan Kumar asked for some code, I am giving the function:

```
function keydownEvent(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 9 || e.which == 9) {// Tab pressed

        //here I want to get the Column Index/Name from which key is pressed
    }

    if (e.keyCode == 113 || e.which == 113)  //f2 press
    {
        var rowid = $('#myGrid').getGridParam("selrow");
        ondblClickRowEvent(rowid, rowid, 1, e);
    }
}
```

Sorry, I thought it was implicit. My mistake!
HTML:

```
<table id='myGrid' ></table>
```

Comment: What you have `tried`? Or give `some code` with `html` or `fiidle`.

Comment: **With html** how could we know where you are pressing? What is `#myGrid`? Is this a `input box` or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. Solved it.

In the `keydownEvent(e)` function you can get the name by the `event e`

`e.target.name == "Your_Column_Name" || e.srcElement.name == "Your_Column_Name"`